# prometheus in docker can't access host jmeter metrics on 9270

Tags: docker, jmeter, prometheus

I have created a docker monitoring file which includes cadvisor/prometheus/grafana and I want to integrate jmeter into it, the compose file is below:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.1
    platform: linux/aarch64
    container_name: cadvisor
    privileged: true
    # database name. Uses db 'cadvisor' by default
    devices:
      - /dev/kmsg:/dev/kmsg
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:ro
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk:/dev/disk:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /cgroup:/cgroup:ro
      - /etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id:ro
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8005:8080"
    networks:
      - monitoring

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./docker/prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus-data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/console'
      - '--storage.tsdb.retention=200h'
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    networks:
      - monitoring

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - monitoring

volumes:
  app:
  dbData:
  prometheus-data: {}
  grafana-data: {}

networks:
  monitoring:
    driver: bridge
```

The problem is that jmeter is running on the host, whereas it pushes the data to localhost:9270/metrics. However, the prometheus gives error that it can't access this site, below is my prometheus config file:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']

  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'jmeter'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['172.17.0.1:9270']
```

I tried to change the ip from docker0, aka 172.17.0.1 to the ubuntu virtual machine eth0 10.211.55.5 but still has no effect.

Comment: Options: 1. Run `jmeter` under Docker Compose; 2. Bind the Docker Compose services to the host's network ([`network_mode`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode)); 3.Make the host DNS-resolvable in the Docker Compose network.

Comment: @DazWilkin I really appreciate your quickly help, option 1 is not suit for my case but option 2 works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @DazWilkin help, I have added this line to my compose file

```
network_mode: "host"
```

which binds promethus to my host network for accessing the metrics.